# How can I unify my email, calendar and tasks (2 exchange accounts + 1 gmail)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, gmail, exchange

This is my situation:

I work as a consultant, and thus work out of multiple computers:

- my work-laptop
- a desktop at my primary client
- my desktop at home
- an android smartphone
- an android tablet

Likewise, I have multiple accounts:

- A Microsoft Exchange (2010 AFAIK) account
- A Microsoft Exchange (2007 AFAIK) account
- A gmail account

The most important thing I need is the ability to have events in one calendar affect the free / busy status of all other accounts (so that if I am busy on Monday 9am with an event from my employer's account, it will show that time as busy in my client's account, and in the gmail account.

Second thing I need is a unified view of all of my accounts' info: Appointments, email, tasks, and contacts (in that order of importance).

I've already tried **Outlook** synchronization tools such as gSyncit, to sync both exchange accounts with gmail, but this creates a mess when updating appointments (deleted appointments sometimes return, timestamps revert).

Is there perhaps some way to at least synchronize the free/busy state in a way that all of my calendar apps / accounts will look there to see if I can be invited? Just solving that would be well worth my while.

Answer (score 1):

unless you have to have outlook enviroument for exchange or something like that, i would go with a gmail based everything, and have send-as authentication from gmail to both xch accounts.

google calender lets you import other calendars, and if your exhcnage publishes it's calendar feed, you can get a live one as well.   otherwise i would import all existing meetings from it, and keep working from google calendar.    This one does publish a public feed if you tell it to, so anyone can see you free//bus times, or more if you set it so.

need more details?
a

edited for more details >>

to get send as just go in gmail settings > accounts and import > Send Mail As    and add an account.  you might need to get some info from your XCH postmaster

- > http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563

the exchange feed i dont remember by heart but you can probably get it from your outlook. 
google it.

soryy i cant reply to your msg up there but im lacking points here..

Comment: This sounds great. A few questions though:

 - How do I get the exchange feed (assuming my servers publish them)?
 - How do I set up gmail to have send-as auth?
 - How do I make sure that my gmail F/B status is checked by people in the exch domains who  try adding me to their meetings?

Comment: Also, do you know where I can find the URL for my google calendar, so that I can set the WebDAV sync from Outlook to google?